# showing product from specific categories in homepage!

Tags: product, magento-1.9, category

I am wondering how do I display products from chosen category in my homepage?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page refer this. Next time first google.

Comment: @Simon :didn't you see my below answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your home page (CMS page)

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Just search "*show products from a category in home page magento*" in google. You will get a tons of results that showing how to do this. Next time don't miss it. Ok ? :)

[Use this link now](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page)

**Note**: dont forget to change the id of category.